# URL for Facebook album id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get URL for Facebook album id (fbid) without any request?

Like I can get URL for photo - `https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=FBID`

I need a valid URL for use with Graph API in link field.

`http://www.facebook.com/FBID` - is not valid, because shown as plain text in link field.

Comment: What does the album ids you have look like? Could you link like http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.1256641940078.2033301.1350507602

Comment: 1256641940078.2033301.1350507602 - this is fbid.albumid.userid. I have only first one (fbid).

Answer (score 4):

If albumid is 1256641940078, the URL is

```
http://www.facebook.com/1256641940078
```

Nodes in the Graph API have a unique ID and you can generally link to anything like this if you just know that ID. For example you can even link to a person like http://www.facebook.com/297200003

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/FBID?fields=link
```

Example: http://graph.facebook.com/537137506325516?fields=link

You better use user access token for private photo.